# In Google Play, can I transfer an app from one developer account to another?

Tags: android

I have an app on Google Play. Can I transfer it to another Google Play developer account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 36):

Yes.  As of March 2014, the correct place to start is here: [Transfer your application](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213).

That page while guide you through the process of preparing both accounts for the transfer and then take you to the form to initiate the transfer.

Comment: I want to transfer only one app.

Comment: @DK5 I know you only want to transfer one, the question is whether that one is all you have.  In any case, I've just updated my answer with a link for the second scenario, so you're covered either way.

Comment: Does transferring an app resets its download statistics?

Comment: @MasterScrat In the first case, no: it says, "When applications are transferred, all ratings, comments, metrics, and users will be preserved."  In the second case, I can't say for sure, but my guess is no.

Comment: also what about payment key and products ids?
will they change?

Comment: Transfer you application: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213

Comment: App transfer is successful. But the Developer name is the old one and not the new one. How can I solve this??

Comment: @DarshanRivkaWhittle just wondering will there be any record left in the original developer account regarding the app? E.g. any transfer history / record regarding the app?

Answer (score 8):

Successful transfer of one application from one account to another.

filled request on https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appt

needed items:

Developer name - https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ - Settings / Account details / DEVELOPER PROFILE

Google Wallet Transaction ID for Original Developer Account Registration
- there is a link in "?" https://wallet.google.com/manage/
- it is payment "Developer Registration Fee" - down of detail page - ID transaction

App names and APK file names ...
We input one of our applications, from https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ - All applications / Store Listing - name and package name (text in header left from published button)

After one day email arrived that transfer is completed. And it was.

Comment: Quick question, do you need to use the hash key from the first dev, or you can use your's (if both app key are different) ?

Comment: @Tsunaze I didnt use any hash keys, just names (my developer name from developer setting) and for application only application name and file name (from application list / store listing). In my opinion most imprortant is original and target email, original and target Wallet Transaction ID (proof, accounts are payd) and App name and APK filename (for one application - both on one line).

Comment: @jir what about the statistics? were they transfered?

Comment: I followed this link and worked for me I follow this link and worked for me https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?visit_id=1-636572578783628427-2639181401&rd=1

Comment: @jir, will there be any record left in the original developer account regarding the app? E.g. any transfer history / record regarding the app ?

Answer (score 1):

Just fill this form: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/appt

A really WTF addition: if the Google Play accounts are very old, your Google Wallet Transaction ID could be like this: `12345678901234567890.G.123456789012345`. As this format was not accepted by the form, I decided to contact Google.

Luckily, they gave the solution: just replace all the characters before the `.G` with `0`. The result is something like `0.G.123456789012345`. And it worked :·)

Comment: just wondering will there be any record left in the original developer account regarding the app? E.g. any transfer history / record regarding the app?

Comment: Nope, the original developer becomes totally clean. Zero record about the moved app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case where I have only used internal testing, it was enough to simply delete the app in account dev A, and then upload the app with the same configuration (package name + signing) to dev account B.